# Objective-C: Play Youtube Video on App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube-api

I am trying to explore what else can i do in iOS app development and it just now that i've tried to include a video on my app.

I have this code below that aims to play a youtube video when the view loads, but all i got is just a black webView.

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://youtu.be/Wq_CtkKrt1o";

videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
videoView.opaque = NO;
videoView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:videoView];


NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
             <html>\
             <head>\
             <style type=\"text/css\">\
             iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
             body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
             </style>\
             </head>\
             <body>\
             <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
             </body>\
             </html>", videoURL];

[videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Are you trying this on the simulator or device?

Comment: @MikeD i'm testing it on the device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to use embed link

use below code

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Wq_CtkKrt1o";
```

instead of

```
NSString *videoURL = @"http://youtu.be/Wq_CtkKrt1o";
```

try this your problem will solve

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. But, I've tried it on my iPad 4th Gen and It has no sounds, on Mini the sounds is good. Why is that? I've checked all the settings for sounds and it is all good.

Comment: what are iOS version respectively ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the code below it works fine for me

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head>\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
    [videoView release];
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Do I need to include any framework for implementing this??

Comment: can you have a look at this link your youtube url is the problem it seems. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html

Comment: code working, but video is not playing, give any solution as soon as possible

Comment: trying in simulator ?. what youtube url your are using .