# Embedding Youtube Videos in iPad app that play in app (not launching youtube app)

Tags: ios, ipad, youtube, embed, in-app

I am trying to understand if this is absolutely not possible and do not feel that I have found a definitive answer.

I need the video content to play in app and not transfer my users over to the youtube app automatically to watch.

Any help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Play Youtube Video on App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490919/objective-c-play-youtube-video-on-app)

Comment: Actually you can do so. See the answer of the duplicated question.